# What is the class, interface, or enum error I keep recieving

Tags: java, class, interface, enums, jcreator

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.powerbot.core.script.job.Task;
import org.powerbot.core.script.job.state.Node;
import org.powerbot.core.script.job.state.Tree;
import org.powerbot.game.api.util.Timer;

public abstract class ScriptWrapper extends org.powerbot.core.script.ActiveScript {

    public final Timer runTime;
    private Tree jobContainer = null;
    private List<Node> jobs;


    public ScriptWrapper() {
        runTime = new Timer(0);
        jobs = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Node>());
    }

    public final void provide(final Node job) {
        if(!jobs.contains(job)) {
            jobs.add(job);
            jobContainer = new Tree(jobs.toArray(new Node[jobs.size()]));
        }
    }

    public final void revoke(final Node job) {
        if(jobs.contains(job)) {
            jobs.remove(job);
            jobContainer = new Tree(jobs.toArray(new Node[jobs.size()]));
        }
    }

    public final void submit(final Task task) {
        getContainer().submit(task);
    }

    public final ScriptWrapper getScriptWrapper() {
        return this;
    }

    public abstract void onStart();

    @Override
    public int loop(); {
        if (jobContainer != null) {
            final Node job = jobContainer.state();
            if (job != null) {
                jobContainer.set(job);
                getContainer().submit(job);
                job.join();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.powerbot.core.event.listeners.PaintListener;
import org.powerbot.core.script.job.state.Node;
import org.powerbot.game.api.Manifest;
import org.powerbot.game.api.methods.Widgets;
import org.powerbot.game.api.methods.input.Mouse;
import org.powerbot.game.api.methods.interactive.Players;
import org.powerbot.game.api.methods.node.GroundItems;
import org.powerbot.game.api.methods.node.Menu;
import org.powerbot.game.api.util.Filter;
import org.powerbot.game.api.util.Random;
import org.powerbot.game.api.util.Timer;
import org.powerbot.game.api.util.node.Deque;
import org.powerbot.game.api.util.node.Queue;
import org.powerbot.game.api.wrappers.Tile;
import org.powerbot.game.api.wrappers.interactive.Player;
import org.powerbot.game.api.wrappers.node.GroundItem;
import org.powerbot.game.bot.Context;
import org.powerbot.game.client.Client;
import org.powerbot.game.client.MenuGroupNode;
import org.powerbot.game.client.MenuItemNode;
import org.powerbot.game.client.NodeDeque;
import org.powerbot.game.client.NodeSubQueue;


@Manifest(authors = { "Cup" }, name = "c[DropParty]")
public class DropParty extends ScriptWrapper implements PaintListener {
    private ArrayList<Tile> locations = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    private ArrayList<Long> times = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private Timer timer = new Timer(0);
    private Player player;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        provide(new VexillumCloser());
        provide(new StatueCloser());
        provide(new Walk());
        provide(new Pickup());
        provide(new Tracking());
    }
    private class VexillumCloser extends Node {
        @Override
        public boolean activate() {
            return Widgets.get(1107, 156).validate();
        }
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            Mouse.hop((int) Widgets.get(1107, 156).getBoundingRectangle().getCenterX(), (int) Widgets.get(1107, 156).getBoundingRectangle().getCenterY());
            Mouse.click(true);
        }
    }
    private class StatueCloser extends Node {
        @Override
        public boolean activate() {
            return Widgets.get(21, 42).validate();
        }
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            Mouse.hop((int) Widgets.get(21, 42).getBoundingRectangle().getCenterX(), (int) Widgets.get(21, 42).getBoundingRectangle().getCenterY());
            Mouse.click(true);
        }
    }

    private class Walk extends Node {
        @Override
        public boolean activate() {
            return Menu.isOpen() && Menu.contains("Walk");
        }

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            if (Menu.isOpen()) {
                select(Menu.contains("Take") ? "Take" : "Walk");
            }
        }
    }
```

The error starts at line 63 :
}
import java.awt.Color;

I've been trying to fix this code sent to me by a friend, but I just can't fix this error; this is probably because I am a beginner, please help thanks.

Comment: Is all this placed within the same file?

Comment: These two classes should be in their own files. Each with its own set of `import` statements.

Comment: Is the code posted a single class or more than one class?

Comment: Yes this is all in one file and this isn't the entire code, just part of it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, each class must be in its own file.  The compiler doesn't expect to see any imports (or really anything else) after the end of the ScriptWrapper class definition.

Put DropParty in its own DropParty.java file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put each class into its own file, unless you nest a private class. You have multiple public classes in the same file, so the compiler doesn't expect to see anything after the closing bracket from the first class definition.